# Can I make a RH inswing exterior door into a Left hand reverse outward swing

Tags: doors

I  have purchased a wrong door , Im a carpenter and don't know if its possible to change the door from a Right hand inward swing to a Lt hand reverse swing door ?

Comment: In general, maybe.  But a photo of the door would help.  Is it symmetrical?  Came pre hung?  Was the lockset drilled? See also http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2784/how-do-you-determine-if-a-door-is-right-handed-rh-or-left-handed-lh?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

a Right Hand Reverse door is the same as a Left Hand (push) door.  You will have to flip the frame around or re-prep it for the strike and hinges though.

Answer (score 0):

It will work just fine but do you want your hinges on the outside?  If this is an interior door no big deal.  If it is an exterior door I could get in your house with a pick and hammer.