# How to find a Pella multipoint locking gear box replacement?

Tags: repair, doors, lock

The gear box for my locking French doors broke.  I am not sure how to find the exact replacement part or if it is even available.  The Pella service team will attempt to schedule a service call, but I am wary of how much they will charge for that.  This is a simple repair; I just need to get the correct part.  The link below LOOKS like the right part, but the company said they could not confirm without a home visit.  Any ideas on if I could find the inner part to replace or anyone else that has done this same repair?

[Pella Part](https://www.pella.com/shop/parts/configure/?id=wood-hinge-patio-door-mortise-locks-panel-locks&type=part&heading=Mortise+Locks+%2F+Panel+Locks+For+Hinge+Patio+Door&options=Operation+%2F+Venting%3DUnhanded%2CBrand%3DDesigner+Series%2CSelect+Part%3D00%2C)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have a Pella dealer local to you? I'd bring the busted one down and see if they can verify the part number. They'll offer to order it (for more than the online price, I'd venture); whether that's worth it is up to you. If you're really lucky, they'll go into the parts bin and find the doohickey you need.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few properties of such hardware that can help confirm the correct replacement parts, assuming you can't do a positive serial number search, but sometimes it still comes down to a bit of a gamble. Here's how I'd work the problem.

1. Establish your door type (model or series) and year of manufacture. Some parts lookup systems use year to determine which generation of a similar product you have.
2. Verify [swing](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/2786/35141), size, and other aspects of your door. There may be opposing, symmetrical options for each swing, for example.
3. Look for any dimensions provided. Sometimes hardware is offered in several sizes, but it looks almost identical in photos without a size reference. Actual dimensions are a very good corroborator.
4. As a final check, scrutinize the details of the part. Every hole, corner, connection, and shape should match (unless your part has a newer version, which does complicate things). If you spot differences, consider whether the position and function appear to be compatible.

If all those things seem to align with the universe, you're probably ok. Check return policy (or resale potential) if you're still in doubt. Then cross your fingers and click the button.